# Linux convert a number into a string on the 6th column

Tags: linux, sed

I created a script that extracts data from a database and loads it to a csv file. I am using SunOS hstz1454 5.10 system. Is there a way I can translate/convert a number to a string on my csv file. So if my 6th column is number `1`, convert it to a string `Cos4`  or if it has `2` on the 6th column convert it to another string `Cos6`. I used a script before that convert the last char into a string. Might be similar to what I am trying to do.

```
for fname in conv2015_10_TrafficProfile_data_migration.csv
do
echo "Translate each char to a string $fname"
    sed s'/S$/STANDARD/g; s/C$/CUSTOMER/g;   $fname > tmp.tmp
mv tmp.tmp $fname
done
```

my data looks like this below:

```
4,2,64,1088,80,1,Y,Y
5,2,64,1088,95,2,Y,Y
6,2,1088,39813120,0,2,Y,Y
7,2,1088,39813120,5,1,Y,Y
8,2,1088,39813120,10,2,Y,Y
```

Comment: To be a bit pedantic: you mean *replace* number with string? Not *convert*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want awk.  In my opinion, is almost never any reason to use sed over awk, for anything other than trivial substitutions (not much more complex than `sed -e 's/this/that'`). In this case it is particularly counterproductive.

You can tell awk to use , as a separator, using `-F,`. We can also put a comma into awk's `OFS` variable (output field separator) so that the `print` command which re-combines the positional fields will combine them with a comma:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," } ...'
```

Now we stick in the logic. Awk supports a kind of "reactive programming", in that it allows assignment to the positional field variables `$1`, `$2`, ...  When you assign to any of these, it automatically reconstitutes the `$0` variable which originally holds the input line. It reconstitutes it by combining the positional fields, with `OFS` in between. Thus, we can do:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
         { if ($6 == 1) $6 = "Cos4"
           else if ($6 == 2) $6 = "Cos6"
           print }' yourfile
```

No regexing required; if you revisit this six months later, it will be almost instantly obvious what it does.

The above code can be streamlined a little by factoring out the conditional tests into individual awk rules. That is to say:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
         $6 == 1 { $6 = "Cos4" }
         $6 == 2 { $6 = "Cos6" }
         { print }' yourfile
```

Furthermore, we can "code golf" the `{ print }` by replacing it with a `1`:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
         $6 == 1 { $6 = "Cos4" }
         $6 == 2 { $6 = "Cos6" }
         1' yourfile
```

The constant `1` serves as a Boolean true condition. The condition has no action, so Awk supplies a default action which is `{ print }`. However, now if you revisit that six months later, you will have to remember this; shortening programs in this way sometimes creates future debt.

On the other hand, a nice transformation, since we are setting `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block, is to eschew the `-F` option, and just set `FS` in the same block:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
     $6 == 1 { $6 = "Cos4" }
     $6 == 2 { $6 = "Cos6" }
     { print }' yourfile
```

We can use a compounded assignment, a lot like in the C language. Similar, related things should be done close together in a similar way, if possible.

Comment: Upvoted: but your statement that there "is almost never any reason to use sed over awk" is not true (and contributes nothing to your answer).

Comment: @jasonwryan - shhh. the old bird might hear you.

Comment: @Kaz thank your logic worked! Great  answer!

Comment: dang, man. what is the point of offering opinion as fact? who does it serve? if you want to make a statement about how a thing might be better than some other thing, and if you want to do it with any kind credibility, back it up. i dunno if you're right or you'e wrong, but that's only because you make baseless assertions! that's the most basic and fundamental of the [logical fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_fallacy). And anyway, what does your fondness for `sed` have to do with your answer at all?

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks, I added "In my opinion" so that it's not mistaken as an assertion of fact. I refer to  sed in the answer because it appears in the question, which is also tagged `[sed]`.

Comment: @yescobar Glad to hear it worked. The oldest SunOS I currently have access to is a Solaris 10 x86 box. I used only basic awk features that have been in POSIX "forever".  By the way, none of these naive "split on commas" techniques work for real CSV, where you can have fields like "foo,  bar", with commas inside, and whitespace outside of the quotes. Plus mechanisms for escaping the quotes.

Comment: @Kaz how can I make your logic replace the data it in the csv file instead of printing it on the SunOS box?

Comment: @yescobar Redirect the output to a temporary file. If it looks correct, then `mv tempfile original.csv`.

Comment: @Kaz I was trying that earlier but did not work but I guess I was missing something, now I got it to work thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e's/,/&Cos\n/5' \
    -e's/\n1/4/'     \
    -e's/\n2/6/'     \
    -e's/Cos\n//' <in >out
```

I never did understand `awk`, though.